# Current and infinite coils/resisotrs/capacitors

Tags: electric-current, capacitance

I have come across a lot of problems that revolve around finding equivalent resistance/capacity/inductivity. But, I can never learn the "tricks" for solving that kind of question. I just can't see those symmetries and how you can "relapse this with that because it is so obvious". Again, I'm asking if there are some broad ideas and rules that I should know for completing that kind of problem.
PS I am providing you with an example
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to simplify these types of arrangements of components you need more advanced methods than simply combining series and parallel components. One such method is called the "Pi to Tee" conversion, also known as the "Delta to Wye" conversion. See the figure below.

After making appropriate conversions the circuit can often be simplified. You can obtain the applicable equations for the conversions on the web. Just google Pi to T or Delta to Wye conversion.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: both answeres really helped!

Answer (score 0):

The 'trick' has little to do with the solving of traditional electrical networks. Look for what I would call a 'repetition symmetry', that is to say a part of the infinite network that can be 'duplicated' one step back from the network terminals, set it to an unknown impedence Z, and then solve for Z with teh 'full' and 'stepped back' versions of the network.

Probably easier to explain with a diagram. For example to to find Rac, where the resistors are all unit value...

[image]

Different problems will have different but similar tricks.